# Unexpected FAIL with :exists in raku

Tags: hash, key, exists, raku

While trying to debug program code I ran into the following:

```
(base) hsmyers@BigIron:~$ rlwrap -A raku

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my regex N { <[A..G]> };
regex N { <[A..G]> }
> my %h = A => 1, B => 2;
{A => 1, B => 2}
> 'B' ∈ %h.keys
True
> my $m = 'B' ~~ / <N> /;
｢B｣
 N => ｢B｣
> $m ∈ %h.keys
False
> $m.Str ∈ %h.keys
True
> my $n = $m.Str
B
> $n ∈ %h.keys
True
> %h<B>:exists
True
> %h<$n>:exists
False
>
```

In sum the question is how do you go from match object to string such that %whatever:exists will work. 'Element of keys' provides a workaround, but I believe that is not the correct way to check for key existence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put matches in `Str` context by using ~, but I think the problem is your case is that you're using literal quotes `<>` for a variable. `%h<$n>` returns the value corresponding to the literal key $n. You need to use %h{$n} to retrieve the value corresponding to the content of `$n`. Also, if $n contains a `Match` it will be put in Str context, so that should work.

Comment: Got it in one! I apologize for the ignorance of the question given the answer :) I can only say that I was copying from the official documentation. Perhaps If I had re-read several more times I would have gotten it. Lack of sufficient examples has been a problem…

Comment: No apologies asked, none needed. We're here to help. And if you appreciate some confusing remarks in the documentation, please raise an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`<a b c>` is a shortcut for `qw<a b c>`.
Which will end up as `'a', 'b', 'c'`

The way to access a Hash by key is with `{}`

```raku
%h{'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Which would be nicer to write as:

```raku
%h{<a b c>}
```

What would be even nicer is to get rid of the `{}`

```raku
%h<a b c>
```

That is why that is valid Raku syntax.

So when you write this:

```raku
%h<$n>
```

It is basically the same as:

```raku
%h{'$n'}
```

---

If you are accessing only one element, and it has no whitespace.
Rather than doing this all of the time:

```raku
%h{'abc'}
```

It is much simpler to just use:

```raku
%h<abc>
```

Which is why all of the documentation uses that form.

---

Similarly these are also the same:

```raku
$/{<a b c>}
$/<a b c>
$<a b c>
```

So if you see `$<abc>` it is really looking inside of `$/` for the value associate with the key `abc`.

There is a lot of syntax reuse in Raku. `<>` is one such case.

---

Note:

You don't need to use `.keys` on a Hash with `∈`.

```raku
'B'  ∈  %h;   # True
```

(Since Raku uses different operators for different operations, it is rare that you would have to do such data massaging.)